# Suspend does not work on Asus X553M laptop in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS with Linux 4.15 kernel

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, suspend

My Asus X553M laptop won't go into suspend state when using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS with Linux 4.15.x kernel. The screen just goes blank but power does not blink to indicate suspend state. The computer won't wake up either - I will have to turn power completely off to continue. This does not happen when I select Linux 4.13.x kernel from start menu: the laptop goes to sleep and wakes up properly.

I already downgraded my 18.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS in hope that I would be able to use Linux 4.13 for longer but I just noticed 16.04 LTS is updating itself to 4.15 kernel as well.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS uses the 4.4 kernel, but 16.04.x LTS uses the HWE (hardware enablement stack) kernels meaning kernel jump versions every six months which is useful for later hardware (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).  The original 4.4 kernel of 16.04 LTS gets security patches back-ported to it, so if you're happy with kernel 4.4 you could always install the original 16.04 LTS (and then update, as you'll have lots of updates given it's the 2016.April iso).  The 4.13 kernel reaches EOL in a few days anyway (it's the 17.10 kernel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to reinstall the system; in 16.04 you can install the original 4.4 kernel, supported until 2021 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A16.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support).

Simply open a package manager, like Synaptic, and install the packages `linux-generic-lts-xenial` and `xserver-xorg-lts-xenial` which should trigger the installation of the other necessary packages. Then reboot and under 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' select the 4.4 kernel. Make sure it works as expected before you uninstall the newer kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (the original release kernel) uses the 4.4 kernel, but any 16.04.x LTS (updated iso) uses the HWE (hardware enablement stack) kernels meaning kernels jump version every six months; useful for later hardware. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for info.

The original 4.4 kernel of 16.04 LTS gets security patches back-ported to it, so if you're happy with kernel 4.4 you could always install the original 16.04 LTS (*and then update, as you'll have lots of updates given it's the 2016.April iso*).

Please note: the 4.13 kernel reaches EOL in a few days, as it's the 17.10 kernel

Comment: *ps:  if you install the 16.04 LTS iso, be sure not to enable the HWE/enablement stack kernel upgrades; or you'll find yourself in the same position as now.*